# How to sort a permutation by reversing subsequences (taken from Skiena 3rd ed.)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've been stuck on the second part of the following question from Skiena (The Algorithm Design Manual, 3rd ed.) for the past 24 hours and it's driving me nuts! I'm struggling to come up with new ideas at this point, and would appreciate some tips/solutions.

**Exercise 4-27**
Suppose you are given a permutation *p* of the integers 1 to *n*, and seek
to sort them to be in increasing order [1, . . . , *n*]. The only operation at your
disposal is *reverse(p,i,j)*, which reverses the elements of a subsequence *(p_i, ..., p_j)*
in the permutation. For the permutation [1, 4, 3, 2, 5] one reversal (of the second
through fourth elements) suﬃces to sort.

- Show that it is possible to sort any permutation using *O(n)* reversals.
- Now suppose that the cost of *reverse(p,i,j)* is equal to its length, the number of elements in the range, *|j − i|* + 1. Design an algorithm that sorts *p* in *O(nlog^2n)* cost.

The first part appears fairly straightforward if we brute-force it: locate the position of the largest/smallest value and reverse the subsequence that will place it in the correct position. Repeat for the next largest/smallest value until the sequence is in the correct order. Clearly this requires *n* reversals at most.

But if I apply this brute-force approach to the second part of the question, it seems like the cost could be *O(n^2)* in the worst-case scenario. Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an algorithm for in-place merge sort that fits:

1. Sort the beginning half of the array;
2. Sort the last half of the array;
3. Merge the two halves in-place.

The merge takes O(N log N) time:

1. Determine the number of elements in the first half that belong in the second half;
2. Swap those last elements in the first half with the first elements in the second half.  You can do this with 3 reversals
3. Recursively merge the 2 pieces in the first and last halves

Since merge takes O(N log N) time, the whole sort takes O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) time.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working through your answer to make sure I fully understand it. Could you clarify a little about what you mean when you say 'recursively merge the 2 pieces in the first and last halves'? And also how the O(N log N) cost for the merge appears? (I'm familiar with the O(N log N) cost for merge using normal operations, but I'm not sure how to derive it when only reverse operations are allowed.)

Comment: Merge: 13570246 -> 1302 5746 ->   10 32 54 76 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: How do we know that we can swap all elements in the first half that belong in the second half in cost O(N log N)? I see that the 'swapping' for sequence 13570246 is fairly straightforward, but a sequence like 72516043 is a bit more complicated. How can I show in general that this swapping can be done in O(N log N), using only reverse operations that have a cost proportional to their length?

Comment: Merging is only the last part of the algorithm.  As in merge sort, the first step is to completely sort the first and second halves of the array.

Comment: I'm sorry for dragging this out a little but I still don't follow. How do we completely sort the first and second halves of the array (using only reverse operations)? Isn't this equivalent to the original problem?

Comment: You recursively call the whole algorithm, which is a sort.  Yes, it's equivalent to the original problem, but at half the size.  When you get to size=1, you can just return

Comment: I'll make one more attempt (sorry!) at articulating my issue as I still don't quite understand. We have two sorted arrays of length N/2. How do we merge these two arrays (using *only* reverse operations, and where the cost of a reverse operation is proportional to its length) in O(N log N)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing a few more notes to Matt Timmermans' excellent answer in case anyone needs more details (like I did) in the future.

Assume we have two sorted sequences *a_1 < ... < a_n* and *b_1 < ... < b_n*. We want to merge these two sequences into a single sorted sequence *c_1 < ... < c_{2n}*. We begin by finding the largest *k* such that *b_1, ..., b_k* are among the *n* smallest values in the final sorted set. We can do this in *O(2n)*. By symmetry, *a_{n-k+1}, ..., a_n* must be among the *n* largest values in the final sorted set.

We can use the reverse operation to swap *a_{n-k+1}, ..., a_n* and *b_1, ..., b_k* with cost *O(2k)*. We now have 4 sequences: *a_1 < ... < a_{n-k}*, *b_k > ... > b_1*, *a_n > ... > a_{n-k+1}* and *b_{k+1} < ... < b_n*. The sequences *b_k, ..., b_1* and *a_n, ..., a_{n-k+1}* are in reverse order due to the original reverse operation. Hence we apply another reverse operation to both sequences to order them correctly. This has cost *O(2k)*.

We have now halved size of our original problem with cost ~ *O(n)*. Our reduced problem is to merge the ordered sequences *a_1 < ... < a_{n-k}* and *b_1 < ... < b_k*, and also to merge the ordered sequences *a_{n-k+1} < ... < a_n* and *b_{k+1} <  ... < b_n*. The sequence bookkeeping gets a little hairy at this point but it's helpful to think about the special situation of *k=n/2* to get a feeling for the general approach.

For *k=n/2*, we have an identical situation as our original problem (two sorted sequences of equal size), except we now have two pairs of sequences, each with half the length of our original problem. So we can repeat our approach for the original problem on these new pairs of sequences. This will again split the size of our problem in two with cost *2O(n/2)*. In general, for *2^m* pairs of ordered sequences of length *n/2^m*, the cost will be *2^m O(n/2^m)* i.e. *O(n)*.

By repeatedly splitting our problem by a factor of 2 and at a cost of *O(n)* for each split, we see that this recursive approach will allow us to merge our original sequences with cost at most *O(n logn)*.

Thus we can merge two ordered sequences of length *n* using the reverse operation with cost at most *O(n logn)*. By applying another recursive approach (like in traditional sorting algorithms) we find that we can sort arbitrarily ordered sequences in *O(n log^2n)*.